# create repeating regions in website

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I currently use Dreamweaver for my website. It allows me to create a template for all code that I want repeated in other pages. This allows me to make a change to the template and it'll update all the other pages that are linked to the template.

How do you do this without Dreamweaver? Do you link the pages to the original HTML/ CSS file?

Answer (score 3):

If by repeated regions you mean areas such as the **footer**, which is generally the same in each web page, then you would normally create a file (e.g. footer.html) and then include that in each of your web pages.

For example as I use PHP, i would use the following wherever I wanted my footer to appear.

```
<?php include "footer.html"; ?>
```

This way, when you want to change the footer, you only have to do it in one place. Good practice is to identify the parts (or regions) of your site which will be the same in all your web pages and then use the process above to organise your code.

For more visual control, you should make sure that all your web pages link to the CSS file of your choice.

I hope I understood your question.

Answer (score 2):

Professional web developers (generally) don't write flat HTML files. Instead they use server-side scripts such as PHP, Perl, and ASP.NET to create parts of a website.

This allows developers to separate the content from the structure from the styles etc.

Oftentimes content management systems are used. Two very popular open-source ones are [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org/) and [WordPress](http://www.wordpress.org/).

As a simple example, variables can be populated from a database, and placed into a template looking something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<?php echo $styles, $scripts; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php echo $header, $content, $nav, $footer; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver can write these for you too.  If you create a separate text file somewhere in your site directory, say */includes/*, you can select *Insert > Server-Side Include* and pick out your text file in the includes folder.  Dreamweaver will insert the code for you.

I'll add that I use sever-side includes and template pages together and find that they compliment each other nicely, especially useful are optional and repeating regions.